# Crawling hashbangs without ajax

Tags: ajax, seo, web-crawler, google-search

I have an website with implemented hashbangs instead of hashtags.
What I mean, I have inner sections which are hidden and when user click on some icon, an section for this icon appears.
My goal is that I want to target google to index my inside links and show them on search results.
Thats why I implement hashbangs instead of just using hashtags.

My question is: should I put my links in sitemap.xml file?
And second question: I have and url: example.com/page#!some-unique-text
Is it right to put in sitemap.xml link: example.com/page/some-unique-text with 301 redirect to: example.com/page#!some-unique-text?

Thank you ALL!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not recommended at all to use 301 redirect or any other kind of redirects in the XML Sitemap.

Always submit your original URL without any redirection.